# 404 Not found Unable to connect to host

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

this has happened recently, it was all fine before but i just don't know what happened. One day i 
opened the launcher and saw this :
[image]

i went on a server and saw i only had a steve skin and everyone else had a steve skin or alex skin (since i play on 1.8) my when my friend went on a server with me she could see my skin and everyone else's. I searched and searched but i couldn't find one soluction to this problem. If you know how to fix this please tell me. (long time ago before this happened i could see my skin and everyone elses but now i can't :c ) (this also happened awhile ago in January)

Comment: Well, you're running an outdated version of Java, so that's a big red flag right there.

Comment: @Dorian No, it says that to everyone until you upgrade to their new launcher with built-in Java.

Comment: is host using a different url or way to launch Minecraft?  Is the Launcher no longer supported?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Don't know if it's just me, but it doesn't say that when I run it.

Comment: @DorianDore It's only on Windows, I should have said, and only if you haven't ever used the .msi installer. Regardless, it's not a sign of a problem, and it does not actually mean that Java is out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you can connect to Minecraft servers, it just means that the launcher couldn't access the Tumblr news feed and the skin server. Not being able to connect to certain sites on the Internet happens occasionally (site go down, or network connections between you and the sites have problems), and usually fixes itself soon, when site or network operators notice a problem with their devices.

If the problem persists, your own computer is being blocked from accessing Tumblr and the skin server for some reason.